# How to use jQuery to add a class-name to sibling elements if an attribute-value is less-than 3>

Tags: jquery, html

How can I add a class-name to sibling elements whose `data-value` attribute-value is less than 3?

jQuery:

```
$("div").hover(function () {
    var it = $(this).siblings();
    if (parseInt(it.attr("data-value")) < 3)
    {
        $(it.addClass("checked"));
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-value="1">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="2">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="3">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="4">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="5">&nbsp;</div>
```

```js
$("div").hover(function() {
  var it = $(this).siblings();
  if (parseInt(it.attr("data-value")) < 3) {
    $(it.addClass("checked"));
  }
});
```

```css
/* edited to have the elements be visible, not present in the original question: */

div {
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
}

div.checked {
  border-color: #0f0;
}

div[data-value]::before {
  content: attr(data-value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-value="1">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="2">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="3">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="4">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="5">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the helper function of `.attr()` to finish out your task,

```
$("div").hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings().attr("data-value", function (_, val) {
        $(this).toggleClass('checked', parseInt(val) < 3);
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xLc85Lt6/1/)

Comment: @ElDiabolo Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

While you already have an accepted answer, I thought I'd offer an alternative:

```js
// the hover() method can take two anonymous functions, the
// first defines the 'mouseenter' action, and the second
// determines the 'mouseleave' action:
$('div').hover(function() {

    // selecting the sibling elements, and filtering
    // that collection to keep only those for whom
    // the assessment within the filter() method returns true/truthy:
    $(this).siblings().filter(function() {

      // if the numeric value of the data-value attribute
      // is less than 3:
      return parseInt(this.dataset.value, 10) < 3;

    // we retain the element(s) in the collection, and
    // add the active class-name:
    }).addClass('active');
  },
  function() {

    // here we simply remove the 'active' class-name on
    // the sibling elements when the <div> is un-hovered:
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div[data-value]::before {
  content: attr(data-value);
}
.active {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-value="1">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="2">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="3">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="4">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="5">&nbsp;</div>
```

Or, in plain JavaScript:

```js
// creating a named-function to handle the events:
function styleSiblings(event) {

  // caching a reference to the hovered/unhovered
  // element:
  var target = this,

  // getting a reference to the siblings by finding the children
  // of the hovered/unhovered element's parentNode; using
  // Array.prototype.slice() to convert that Array-like NodeList into
  // an Array, with Function.prototype.call() to apply the Array
  // method to the NodList:
    siblings = Array.prototype.slice.call(target.parentNode.children, 0)

  // using Array.prototype.filter() to remove the hovered/unhovered
  // element from the collection (retaining only those who are not
  // the 'target' element:
    .filter(function(child) {
      return child !== target;
    });

  // if it's the 'mouseenter' event:
  if (event.type === 'mouseenter') {

    // we iterate over the array of siblings, the
    // 'sibling' variable in the anonymous function
    // is provided automatically, and is a reference to
    // the current element node of the array over which
    // we're iterating:
    siblings.forEach(function(sibling) {

      // if the numerical value of the dataset-value attribute
      // in base-10/decimal, is less than three:
      if (parseInt(sibling.dataset.value, 10) < 3) {

        // we add the 'active' class-name:
        sibling.classList.add('active');
      }
    });
  } else if (event.type === 'mouseleave') {

    // otherwise we simply iterate over the siblings
    // Array and remove the 'active' class-name from
    // each of the contained elements:
    siblings.forEach(function(sibling) {
      sibling.classList.remove('active');
    });
  }
}

// caching a reference to the relevant <div> elements with
// a data-value attribute:
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-value]');

// iterating over that NodeList, using Array.prototype.forEach()
// with Function.prototype.call() to allow us to do so:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
  // the 'div' variable, again, is a provided variable
  // that refers to the current element in the Array over
  // which we're iterating.

  // here we add an eventListener for both the
  // 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events; naming
  // the styleSiblings function as the event-handler
  // note the lack of parentheses which assigns the
  // function rather than the returned-value of that
  // function as the event-handler:
  div.addEventListener('mouseenter', styleSiblings);
  div.addEventListener('mouseleave', styleSiblings);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div[data-value]::before {
  content: attr(data-value);
}
.active {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div data-value="1">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="2">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="3">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="4">&nbsp;</div>
<div data-value="5">&nbsp;</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).